# Was ist ein Schachtzaul?

Tags: meaning, etymology, single-word-request

In Erfurt an der Krämerbrücke findet sich ein "Haus zum wilden Mann & güldenen Schachtzaul".
Weder Duden noch Grimm erwähnen "Zaul", und ich habe das zuvor noch nicht gehört.

Die [Deutsche Stiftung Denkmalschutz](https://www.denkmalschutz.de/presse/archiv/artikel/wo-man-vor-lauter-bruecke-den-fluss-nicht-mehr-sieht.html) weiß dazu scheinbar nur:

> Ein besonders interessantes Haus ist die heutige Nummer 31. Traditionell „Zum wilden Mann und gülden Schachtzaul“ genannt, stammt der teilweise in Sichtfachwerk gehaltene und durch ein Satteldach mit Dachgauben geschlossene Fachwerkbau aus dem 17., vielleicht sogar aus dem 16. Jahrhundert.

Allerdings verspricht ein Prospekt der Langen Nacht der Museen Erfurt von 2013 eine Klärung der Frage:

> Wer wissen möchte, was es mit dem Hausnamen "Zum wilden Mann und güldenen Schachtzaul auf sich hat, erfährt es an diesem Abend"

Ich frage mich, und damit euch, also nun, was ein Schachtzaul ist.
War das Wort mal verbreitet, wo kommt es her und was bedeutet es?

[image: Bild eines Schildes mit der Aufschrift: Haus zum wilden Mann & güldenen Schachtzaul] [image: Flyer-Auszug: Wer wissen will, was es mit dem ... Schachtzaul auf sich hat, erfährt es an diesem Abend]

Answer (score 8):

Zunächst zum Schacht. Laut [Thüringischer Landeszeitung](https://www.tlz.de/web/zgt/thema/detail/-/specific/Erfurts-Wahrzeichen-1-Die-Kraemerbruecke-31-2020949680) befindet sich in der Mitte der unteren Etage in Loch zum Durchlunsen (Durchschauen) im Boden. Das ist mMn der 'Schacht'. 'Zault' ist ein altes Wort für 'Zoll'. Ich vermute, dass Zaul eine Lenisierung von Zault ist. 'Gold' schließlich könnte für Abgaben stehen. Daher meine Vermutung: Der Zoll hat durch dieses Loch den Handelsverkehr/Abgaben kontrolliert.

Folglich wäre der entsprechende Zöllner der 'Schachtzaul'.

Comment: Und was ist ein Eisenknurr?

Comment: Das habe ich vom Knurrhahn abgeleitet. :)

Comment: Also treffen sich dort Waldschrat und Zöllner?

Comment: Gibt es eine Quelle für die Aussage, dass "Zaul" ein altes Wort für "Zoll" ist?

Comment: @IQV "Zault" wird beispielsweise in der Geschichte des Hotels "Am Zault" erwähnt https://hotelamzault.de/de/am-zault/historisches Die Verkürzung zu Zaul kann ich nicht explizit belegen.

Comment: Haben nicht sowieso viele/alle Häuser der Krämerbrücke ein Loch (einen Schacht?) im Boden, um die Waren aus den Lieferschiffen in die Läden der Krämer zu hieven?

Comment: Ja, es könnte auch ein Schacht-Hol sein, wenn es Belege gibt

Comment: "Schacht" ist aber auch ein altes Maß, zusammen mit einer weiteren Angabe ist es ein Volumenmaß daraus: [Schachtrute](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schachtrute), Schachtfuß, Schachtzoll,...